# Multi line text in table cell damaging the view

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I'm using following code to display data from database:

```
 <td><' . nl2br($data->test->normal_value) . '</td>
```

Data is in this form in database:

```
    "ABCDas : 1212
     ABCDas < 1212121212
     ABCDas > 12120000"
```

I want to display it in same way as in database, so I used nl2br.

But the view gone damaged because I used

```
.testvaluetable tr{
        line-height: 1px;
    }
```

following is the screenshot:

[image]

If I remove line-height then display is ok but line height gone high. See following image:

[image]

I want small gap between two rows.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Try changing it from 1px to something more sane, like 20px

Comment: i want to achieve three lines data in Normal value field against shugar but at the same time i want exactly this line-height gap in tables rows.

Comment: Line-height is distance between rows of text, not rows in a table.

Comment: Also you should almost never specify it in pixels. Use unitless numbers for line-height.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović So what can i use so that there is small gap between two rows.?

Comment: Padding on `td`. Or a transparent border, and don't collapse them.

Comment: Please see second image in question....

Comment: I solve it by setting line-height to normal and padding-bottom to 0...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just make `line-height` normal as default

and try `cellspacing="0"` and `cellpadding="0"` in table tag

Comment: there is no effect between rows gap by adding cellspacing="0" and cellpadding="0" in table tag